# How to resume a minimized android app from launch icon?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am beginner in android programming, I am making a music app the problem I am facing with my app is when my app is minimized and I try to resume the app from the launch icon, splash screen appears for the specified time but after that the android home screen appears and when I try to open it again same thing happens, to start the app again I have to force stop the app.

what I am doing in the main activity is to find if device has an internet connectivity the app will stream on-line music but if there is no internet connectivity the app will play downloaded music.

main activity code is given below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// flag for Internet connection status
Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
Boolean responseCode = false;

// Connection detector class
ConnectionDetector cd;

int code;

int splashtime=6000;
Thread splash,t;
ProgressBar pb1;
Handler hd;

SharedPreferences appPreferences;
boolean isAppInstalled = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

appPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
isAppInstalled = appPreferences.getBoolean("isAppInstalled",false);
if(isAppInstalled==false){
    /**
    create short code
    */

    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
    shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.icon));
    intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
    /**
    Make preference true
    */
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = appPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("isAppInstalled", true);
    editor.commit();
}

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// creating connection detector class instance
cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

/**
Check Internet status button click event
*/

// get Internet status
isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

if (isInternetPresent) {
    // Internet Connection is Present
    // make HTTP requests
} 
else {
    // Internet connection is not present
    // Ask user to connect to Internet
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You don't have internet connection.\n Opening Offline Player...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

pb1=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
hd=new Handler();
splash=new Thread(new Runnable(){

@Override 
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //pb1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    synchronized(this)
    {
        try {
                wait(splashtime);
        } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                      e.printStackTrace();
            }

        finally{

           finish();

           // check for Internet status
           if (isInternetPresent) {
                // Internet Connection is Present
                // make HTTP requests
                Intent i=new Intent();
                i.setClass(MainActivity.this, MusicPlayerActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            } 
            else {
                // Internet connection is not present
                // Ask user to connect to Internet
                // Offline Palyer
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OfflineMusicPlayer.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, 100);
            }


        }
    }
}});

splash.start();
}

}
```

app works fine and when minimized the app can be accessed from recent apps button but it can't be resumed from the launch icon.

please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check in MainActivity isTaskRoot(). If activity is not root activity - just finish it.

Also try to debug your MainActivity. Seems like you have a crash there on the second run. Try to fix that or change launchMode for MainActivity.

Comment: just tried the isTaskRoot()  if (!isTaskRoot()) {
            final Intent intent = getIntent();
            final String intentAction = intent.getAction(); 
            if (intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) && intentAction != null && intentAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {
                Log.w("TAG", "Main Activity is not the root.  Finishing Main Activity instead of launching.");
                finish();
                return;       
            }
        }  

but no change